# Как создать базу и приконектиться к ней?

Tags: postgresql, rust, actix-web

Я новичок в серверной разработке + в разработке на языке Rust.
Вопрос:
Как самым примитивным способом создать таблицу базы данных(pg) и приконектиться к ней?
Допустим у меня есть установленный postgresql по следующему пути:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я копирую код из 2-х разных мануалов по подключению к бд:

1. https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/database/postgres.html#create-tables-in-a-postgres-database
2. https://docs.rs/postgres/0.15.2/postgres/

Оба варианта вызываются с ошибкой, как я понимаю не связанной с некорректным(а на данный момент он не корректен) путем к бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где можно найти корректный мануал для чайника или как можно решить вопрос в данном случае?
Примеры с гит хаба(по подключению к бд) излишне нагромождены - хотелось бы разобраться для начала с самой простой ситуацией.

Текущий `Cargo.toml` в проекте следующий:

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Mike_Kharkov <yamaradg@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "2.0"
actix-rt = "1.0"
```

Так же есть дополнительный вопрос:
Если использовать `actix-web` - будет ли как то отличатся подключение к бд в этом случае если не использовать `disel` и надо ли его использовать собственно - какие в этом подходе преимущества?(в 2-х словах.)
(ранее читал, что он не может работать асинхронно.)

Comment: в `Cargo.toml` ты `postgres` прописать не забыл?

Comment: не прописывал - вот текущие настройки:
http://joxi.ru/xAeybQDcXg9XqA
что конкретно необходимо там прописать?
+ после прописывания какой командой активировать новый сетап карго?

Comment: в `[dependencies]` добавить `postgres = "0.15.2"` (или какаю там версию хочешь)... собирать `cargo build`, как обычно — он должен сам собрать и скачать и собрать либу для postgres...

Comment: http://joxi.ru/gmv1nyvH1vkdjr
а как понять вот такого рода ошибку?
карго я так понимаю устраивают только версии 0.17 и т.п. - а что это за версии такие допотопные? )
или что я не так понял в данном случае?
там же версию  базы данных прописывать необходимо - правильно?

Comment: нет, это версия крейта cargo, клиентской библиотеки, а не версия сервера... например у тебя в вопросе ссылка на `0.15.2`: https://docs.rs/postgres/0.15.2/postgres/. Список версий есть там же в левом верхнем углу...

Comment: при первом запуске все сработало без ошибок - вывелось 2 переменные из 3-х (почему то) - далее при повторных запусках этого файла вылетает вот такая ошибка:
http://joxi.ru/L215QxzH0gEDD2
почему это может происходить гипотетически?

Comment: в строке выше ведь прямым текстом написано: «отношение `person` уже существует», очевидно, что такая таблица создалась в базе уже при первом запуске. Чтобы обойти ошибку, воспользуйся конструкцией вида [*CREATE TABELE __IF NOT EXISTS__*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html)